# How to get data by matching month of birthdate from database to current month in laravel using Carbon datetime extension?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I need exactly same results as I have given below in SQL query in Laravel 5.

```
SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE MONTH(birthdate) = MONTH(NOW())    // get get current month's birthday
```

In my **controller**, I have code this.

```
$customer['current_dob'] = Customers::where( DB::raw('MONTH(birthdate)','=','MONTH(NOW())'))->get();
```

**Model:**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customers extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'customers';
    protected $fillable = array('fname','lname','email','mobile','birthdate','aniversary','gender','amount');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good scenario for using `whereRaw`

```
// Get customer with birth date in current month
Customers::whereRaw('MONTH(birthdate) = MONTH(NOW())')->get();

// Get customer with birth date in a specific month
$month = Carbon\Carbon::now()->month; // Current month with Carbon
Customers::whereRaw('MONTH(birthdate) = ?', [$month])->get();
```

Comment: Thanks @Javi. I already did same as you mentioned above and it worked. Thanks again and I appreciate.

Comment: By simply using where:: , It automatically added 'is null' at the end of query. Its resolved by using whereRaw::